# Get a random point (x,y) that is on a portion of a function's curve?

Tags: linear-algebra, graphing-functions

I have a function `xy*100*50 = 1000` that plots the following curve:

[image]

I would like to be able to get a random pair (x,y), where `0<x<1` and `0.5<y<1`. In other words, any pair that will define a point of the curve that is in the red area.

[image]

My goal is to be able to generate a random pair that solves the equation `xy*100*50 = 1000` with x and y being within some variable borders.

Is it possible at all? I have limited mathematical knowledge so I am not sure if it is even doable.

EDIT: @LuLu already gave a simple solution for that case, but the truth is that I am also looking for something that would work in cases like that one:

[image]

Where not all values of x in [2;8] have a matching y between [1;2]. So I can't pick a random x.

Comment: your function is $xy=\frac {1000}{100\times 50}=\frac 15$, yes?  An easy way to get a "random" point on the curve is to choose a uniformly random $y$ between $.5$ and $1$ and then define $x=\frac 1{5y}$.  Or choose an $x$ uniformly between $.2$ and $.4$.  is that good enough for your purposes?

Comment: To stress:  that won't be uniformly random on the curve, it will just have a uniformly random $y$ coordinate.  You can get a value uniformly on the curve but that's more work.

Comment: @lulu Thank you, first defining a smaller limit for x, based on the limits for y makes sense :). It should help with most of my cases. I however edited my question to add another case where it really becomes a problem.

Comment: Well, you can still do it the same way.  It's always easy to take a uniform $x$ even if the domain is more than one interval).  But, do be careful.  Doing it this way definitely introduces a bias in the choice of $y$.  For the first case, for instance, If I choose a uniform $y$, I get an average $x$ of about $.277$ instead of $.3$, so uniform $y$ is not the same as uniform $x$.  Again, I have no idea if this sort of bias is an issue for you.

Comment: I don't think the bias will be an issue for me. Being able to guarantee at least one pair in every case is the most important. I am sorry but I do have trouble understanding everything you describe though. What does "uniform" stand for? Couldn't find a definition online :(. And finally, how can I calculate the intervals where x has a matching y?

Comment: Here is a discussion of the [Uniform Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution). In brief, the uniform distribution on, say, the unit interval $[0,1]$ means that the number selected is equally likely to be anywhere in that interval.  That's what a standard random number generator will hand you (=rand() in Excel, for instance).  As to deciding what your range is...well, that really depends on your function.

Comment: Okay, so uniformity is definitely not a requirement. I understand there is no global solution to calculate the intervals where x has a y? If I could find that, I would be able to solve the problem in all my cases.

Comment: Really, it depends on the function.  It can be quite hard, if the function is complex.